# emacs ess apply function to token under point

Tags: ess, r

I've finally committed to moving over to both `emacs` and `ess` -- and i'm having a bit of trouble getting (the famously customisable) combination to work as i'd like.

Say that i have a file that contains an object called `rainfall` open in emacs and an inferior R session open. Is there a way that i can put point over the token and then send it to the `R` process for a function to be applied to that object?

To make it concrete, say the source file contains the following object:

```
rainfall <- xts(runif(100, min = 0, max = 10), seq.Date(as.Date('2019-01-01'), by = 1, length = 100))
```

I'd like to be able to put `point` anywhere inside the token `rainfall` and (via some keyboard shortcut) send it to the `R` process with some function (such as `head`, `tail`, `plot`, or `summary`) applied to it.

So in the iESS[R] screen i'd see: `R> tail(rainfall)` and the associated output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want quickly with a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#Basic-Keyboard-Macro) for each Emacs session.

But it looks like you would want to have several standard functions available to quickly examine R objects, so it will be more flexible to do it in Emacs Lisp.

```el
(require 'ess-r-mode)
(defun r-summary-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (ess-symbol-at-point)))
    (if sym
        (ess-send-string (get-buffer-process "*R*") 
                         (concat "summary(" (symbol-name sym) ")\n") t)
      (message "No valid R symbol at point"))))

(define-key ess-r-mode-map (kbd "C-c :") 'r-summary-at-point)
```

That function does not check to make sure the "*R*" process buffer exists, but will work once you have started the process, assuming the default.

Comment: I tried this code, but got the error `Symbol's value as variable is void: ess-r-mode-map`.

Comment: Sorry - I know why - I will edit my answer.  You need to require the library first.

Comment: for some reason `ess-r-mode-map` broke things (even if i required it above);  the good news is that this works `(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c :") 'r-summary-at-point)`.  this is probably another question, but if you have an opinion on `ess-r-mode-map` v. `ess-mode-map` i'm interested (or some links!).

Comment: `ess-mode-map` is more general, and probably better to use - but it's been a couple years since I used ESS on a daily basis, so take that with a grain of salt.  The important thing is that you can call the function and it works - the key binding is another matter.  You can always run functions with `M-x eval-expression` or ` a quick `M-:` - always try that before using a key combo!  You probably already know that  :-)

Comment: I've asked a [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58572/general-function-to-concat-token-at-point-with-function-and-send-to-r) -- i'm building up a lot of boilerplate code in my `.emacs` file so i'm trying to figure out how to create a general function so that i can declare on of these in a single line.