# general function to concat token at point with function and send to *R*

Tags: functions, ess, r

I'm moving my `R` setup over to `emacs` and `ess` -- and am struggling with the emacs / LISP customisation process.

In an answer to [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58554/emacs-ess-apply-function-to-token-under-point), I learnt how to create a function that concats a function name with the token at point and sends it to `*R*`.

This was great as a once off -- but now my `.emacs` is filling up with boilerplate code (see the code block at the bottom).

What i'd really like is a way to declare mappings in a single line:

```
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") _concat_summary_token_)
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") _concat_print_token_)
```

The below code-block is an example of what i have at the moment -- two is okay, but i have ten already and plans to add more  ... so i'm going to get lost in boilerplate!

```
(defun r-summary-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (ess-symbol-at-point)))
    (if sym
        (ess-send-string (get-buffer-process "*R*")
                         (concat "summary(" (symbol-name sym) ")\n") t)
      (message "No valid R symbol at point"))))
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'r-summary-at-point)

(defun r-print-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (ess-symbol-at-point)))
    (if sym
        (ess-send-string (get-buffer-process "*R*")
                         (concat "print(" (symbol-name sym) ")\n") t)
      (message "No valid R symbol at point"))))
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") 'r-print-at-point)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you an hint:

```
(defun apply-r-func-at-point (func)
    "Apply R FUNC at point, FUNC should be a string."
    (let ((sym (ess-symbol-at-point)))
    (if sym
        (ess-send-string (get-buffer-process "*R*")
                         (concat  func "(" (symbol-name sym) ")\n") t)
      (message "No valid R symbol at point"))))

(defun r-summary-at-point ()
  (interactive) (apply-r-func-at-point "summary"))
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'r-summary-at-point)

(defun r-print-at-point ()
  (interactive)     (apply-r-func-at-point "print"))
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") 'r-print-at-point)
```

Comment: i've tested this and it works ... but what i would really like is a way to do this all in a single line (combining the `defun` and `define-key` function calls). is that possible?

Comment: @Ricardo: you could with a lambda function, but you're sacrificing a lot of flexibility and readability for the sake of saving 1 line in your init file.

Comment: What are the downsides? I’m learning so I would certainly read a link.  The issue is that I might have twenty of these (or more).